# Can't find plugins button on Ubuntu 16.04 - QGIS Las Palmas

Tags: qgis-plugins, ubuntu

I recently installed QGIS 2.18 'Las Palmas' on my Ubuntu system. I have located the "plugin toolbar" but can't seem to find the actual plugins button.

In this plugins toolbar, the only button present seems to be the python console.

I believe I installed everything properly but I suppose I may have missed some download.

Comment: i think that might be normal on a fresh install - have you installed any plugins yet? (note that not all plugins install an icon there, some only appear in menus or the processing toolbox). Other plugins may have their own toolbars.

Comment: I haven't installed any plugins yet. I thought you installed plugins with the plugins button (which I can't access).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be normal in a fresh install.

The menu option **plugins > manage and install plugins** will let you add plugins. I don't think there's a toolbar button for that.

Bear in mind that not all plugins install an icon to the plugins toolbar - they may appear elsewhere.

- in the plugin / vector / database / web menu
- in their own menu
- in processing toolbox
- in their own toolbar
- in a panel (dock)

Generally, the newer plugins tend to have their own toolbar.

After a while it's easy to get a lot of toolbar clutter. <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on some empty space on any toolbar and you'll get a menu which lets you see which toolbars are enabled and turn them on or off.

Comment: plugins > manage and install plugins isn't even visible :C. I can't even view a menu in my install.

Comment: I just realized it is hidden until you hover over the top bar. Nvm.

Comment: That's Ubuntu's fault btw, not QGIS.